svg TexStudio error: ! Package svg Error: Inkscape version not detected
I am using TexStudio on Windows. I set the --shell-escape option in the pdflatex settings, I am using PdfLatex as compiler and Inkscape is correctly installed and added to PATH.
If I run "inkscape -V" from terminal any error appear.
I load svg package on tex file and this moring it was fine, I was able to use \icludesvg{image.svg} without any error. But now in the evening an error appear, I do not change anything and moreover if I run  pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode filename.tex from terminal it compiles without error.
From Texstudio
filename.tex: avviso: 20: No version of Inkscape was detected by invoking(svg) inkscape -V'(svg) so the Inkscape export will fail quite sure as the(svg) command is probably unknown to your OS. You could set(svg) inkscapeversion=' manually but this is very(svg) unlikely to work
Assignment_1.tex: errore: 206: Package svg Error: Inkscape version not detected. \includesvg[scale = 0.7]{image}.
Any suggestion?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You may have to generate the PDF manually using inkscape. Running as an administrator seems to be bad, according to the comment below.
I had the same problem. If you can run "inkscape -V" in a terminal but TexStudio is unable to detect its version, you can try running TexStudio as an Administrator. It solved the problem for me.

Never run a user application with admin permissions! The strict separation of user and administrator activities is the basis of all computer security. Running user applications as an administrator, on the other hand, is a gateway for malicious code of all kinds.
